# Did the Change Tracking internals change from SQL Server 2008 to 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In trouble shooting an issue with synchronizing disconnected devices with a central database server, we are experiencing a problem after upgrading to SQL Server 2012 on the server.  It appears that the CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION is returning a value 1 higher than it should (or at least than it did prior to the upgrade.)

I have been working thru [Arshad Ali's great walk thru example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1819/using-change-tracking-in-sql-server-2008/) of how to set up a simple example.

I have run the scripts from #1 thru #5 to insert, delete, and update a row in the Employee table in both a SQL Server 2008 and a 2012 environment.

In 2008, the following statement returns a 0:

```
SELECT CHANGE_TRACKING_MIN_VALID_VERSION(OBJECT_ID('Employee'))
```

In 2012, it returns a 1.

Has anyone else experienced this change in behavior?  Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Just an FYI, if you can't get a good answer here, you might want to try the database admin StackExchange site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I submitted an expanded version of the original question to dba.stackexchange and have had one reply thus far.